# App Store Connect disable mails to TestFlight testers

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight

I just found out that **TestFlight testers** receive mail notification from Appstore Connect about app submissions. I only want admin/developers/app managers to receive these mails, not marketing, sales etc.

**Is there any way to disable notification mails per user or per role?**

Ps. I know you can opt out via the TestFlight app but I want manage this myself.